# Zoom Out On Page Messes Alignment

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, image

I have the following code:

```css
.aligned {
  display: flex;
  align-items: top;
}

.p {
  padding: 15px;
}

img {
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

blockquote {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
  padding: 0.35em 40px;
  line-height: 1.45;
  position: relative;
  color: #383838;
}

blockquote:before {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  content: "\201C";
  font-size: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

blockquote cite {
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

blockquote cite:before {
  content: "\2014 \2009";
}
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  height: auto;
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  img {
    float: left;
    height: 200px; /* image height for larger screen only */
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/220px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" width="370" height="500">
<div class="aligned">
  <div class="p">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
    </p>
    <blockquote>
      Nothing Is Impossible. The Word Itself Says 'IM Possible'
      <cite>Audrey Hepburn</cite>
    </blockquote>

  </div>
```

So when you run the above code, open it on a new page, you can see the alignment to be like this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

On my end, it looks like that but when I zoom out on my website, the output gets zoomed out

---

That is what my output looks like when I **zoom out**. I do not want that, is there a way to make it static, meaning even if I zoom out, the output of the above code I sent does not change?

Even if you run the above code, open it on a new page, and zoom out, you can see the text and the image to change its position. However, I want them to be static, meaning not change at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please update the question with the image of what you see? It looks like you meant to supply a screencap but didn't add a URL

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping everything inside a dedicated parent div like so:

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/220px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" width="370" height="500">
  <div class="aligned">
    <div class="p">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
      </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
      </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
      </p>
      <blockquote>
      Nothing Is Impossible. The Word Itself Says 'IM Possible'
         <cite>Audrey Hepburn</cite>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If this won't work, please make a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that illustrates the problem, or share your website address.

Answer (score 0):

You are using media query in the wrong way

If you are going to use height:200px; then you have to set width:auto; so it can take that width.

```css
.aligned {
  display: flex;
  align-items: top;
}

.p {
  padding: 15px;
}

img {
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

blockquote {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
  padding: 0.35em 40px;
  line-height: 1.45;
  position: relative;
  color: #383838;
}

blockquote:before {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  content: "\201C";
  font-size: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

blockquote cite {
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

blockquote cite:before {
  content: "\2014 \2009";
}
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  height: auto;
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  img {
    float: left;
    height: 200px; /* image height for larger screen only */
width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/220px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" width="370" height="500">
<div class="aligned">
  <div class="p">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
    </p>
    <blockquote>
      Nothing Is Impossible. The Word Itself Says 'IM Possible'
      <cite>Audrey Hepburn</cite>
    </blockquote>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the `img` tag in a div container, and set style for the container as follows:

```
.image-flex {            
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}



<div class="image-flex">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/220px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg">
  </div>
```

Basically `display: flex;` will layout contents in the container and `justify-content:center;` will align them in center.